# REST API: How to compress JSON for POST method

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome

I am calling a REST API in my project for creating some records.
Everything is working fine but I got a challenge, the JSON request body is too big (having thousands of keys and values).

Now I want to compress the request body. I tried it using JavaScript

```
var reqJSON = { ... } // too big JSON object
var compressedJSON = JSON.stringify(reqJSON, null, 0); // converting JSON to String (compression)
```

Now I am sending the string in the request body and converting this string into JSON at the server-side.

I am curious, is it the correct way of JSON compression? If yes how can I check the difference in the request body size?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not using a JSON minifier?

Comment: just because you add a comment `converting JSON to String (compression)` doesn't mean there's compression going on. `how can I check the difference in the request body size?` to make a comparison you need two things - you've shown one. What's the other?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't compression at all.

> ```
> var reqJSON = { ... } // too big JSON object
> ```

That will give you a JavaScript object, not JSON. Possibly your Ajax library will convert it to JSON if you pass it. There's no way for us to know. If the data is to get to the server then it will need serializing to *some* format that can be sent over the wire so *something* must be converting it before the HTTP request is made.

> ```
> var compressedJSON = JSON.stringify(reqJSON, null, 0); // converting JSON to String (compression)
> ```

**That** will give you JSON. There's no compression involved though.

---

If you want to compress it then you'd need to look for [a library that can do actual compression](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript%20gzip%20library&t=h_&ia=web).

Answer (score -1):

You can use gzip for compress json its working fine

Comment: How should I achieve `gzip` compress in JavaScript?